# Get sum of all records from result of union query

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 different type of vehicles tables belonging to a passenger vehicle category. I want to get total number of vehicles for passenger category vehicle with status as running.

```
table name -> column names
cars -> id, status, category_id and so on...
vans -> id, status, category_id and so on...
buses -> id, status, category_id and so on...
```

When I try to get just ids and take overall count, I'm getting incorrect result.

```
select count(*) from (
select id from cars where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =3
UNION
select id from vans where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =4
UNION
select id from buses where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =3
    ) x;
```

Overall result is coming 2. however expected result =3

When I try with the following approach, the following query is giving correct result but taking long time to execute.

```
select count(*) from (
select count(*) from cars where category_id = 1 and status = 'NEW'
UNION
select count(*) from vans where category_id = 1 and status = 'NEW'
UNION
select count(*) from buses where category_id = 1 and status = 'NEW'
    ) x;
```

so just to avoid any performance issues, Can anyone suggest a better solution for this problem.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It doesn't make sense that you are getting the correct result with the last query at all. Let's say all those tables have 1 row that matches the criteria, the result would be 1. How that is correct? Maybe you should make it clear giving sample data and desired result.

Comment: I created a DBfiddle, would you check it. I think your last query is not correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ccb1673398a99b4e7e3e75a60c49f66

Comment: I see the problem now, try UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Just wondering in your DBFiddle, why the query was giving wrong result? I am running the same in pgAdmin, it gives correct data.

Comment: In fiddle, all tables have matching 1 record where dept_id = 1 and status='NEW', so all of them return 1 as result and unions cause a single result with 1 row. In second case there is no dept_id=2, all queries with UNIONs return 0, after unioned it is again a single row containing 0 as dept_id, and its count is again 1. If you use that one then you still need to use UNION ALL, but for the outermost select you would use sum() instead of count().

Comment: Okay, now understood. In my case, why I was seeing correct response is because 1 query was not giving any records, ie. 0 as result and 2 of the queries were giving result as 1.
I expected result to be 2, because only two tables have the data, but in this case it was resulting 2 because 2 distinct type of output was coming in result. Got confused. Thanks for explaining @CetinBasoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UNION ALL instead of UNION:

```
select count(*) from (
select id from cars where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =3
UNION ALL
select id from vans where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =4
UNION ALL
select id from buses where category_id = 1 and status = 'RUNNING' -- result => id =3
    ) x;
```

Comment: Yeah, UNION ALL worked. thanks